# How to transfer file to windows server that has 2FA?

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla

Im trying to transfer a zip file from my desktop download folder to an Azure windows 2019 server that is configured with 2FA (Duo authentication).

I downloaded FileZilla and followed the instructions [here](https://unm-student.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7857/%7E/filezilla-ftp-configuration-for-duo-mfa-protected-linux-servers) but Im unable to connect regardless of the many attempts ive tried!
I know the article im following is for linux server but i was thinking the instructions shouldnt be too different for a windows server besides the port (3389 rdp instead of 22 ssh, ftp instead of sftp)

[image: sitemanager]

```
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 10.x.x.xx:3389...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I can RDP to the server just fine and i get a duo push. if FileZilla isnt gonna work for this, what other methods i have to transfer the zip file?
I tried `run > \\hostname\c$` but this doesnt work either

Note: I have to connect to Azure VPN to access the server, is it because its a private IP that this is not working?

Comment: why was this downvoted -_-

Comment: Anyways, i just found out that i can simply copy/paste wth LOL. Still i think this is an interesting question to solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Duo protects the logon to the desktop either locally or remotely, or both. It doesn't protect file access, FTP access, or any other type of access to the server.
2. Port 3389 is the RDP protocol. It cannot be used for file transfers via FPT, SSH, or any other file transfer protocol.
3. In order to connect to an Azure virtual machine using any protocol or port, that protocol or port must be allowed inbound in your Network Security Group or Azure Firewall.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this not sure why people downvoted the post, it was a legitimate question smh